# php-WebSocket fail in establishing connection under Ratchet

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I am new to WebSocket protocol and new to Ratchet websocket. I just follow the steps suggested in http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world and try to build a websocket connection. My code:

bin/chat-server.php

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new Chat(),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
?>
```

and src/MyApp/Chat.php

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

(actually they are the same as the code in the website)

I turn the chat-server.php on in the command line, waiting for clients. And on Chrome, I Open Developer Tools, in console I typed the following code:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

pressed enter, it showd:[image]

it did not show the message "Connection established!".
I checked:
[image]

[image]

it showd pending?

I went to check the server side:
[image]

seems it received the headers?

After a while, it will finally disconnected as timeout:
[image]

So far I think the websocket handshake did not succeed. I tend to believe that the server did not respond correctly, or even did not respond at all? However, I have no idea which part goes wrong. Anyone familiar with Ratchet Websocket and know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Because you connect on `port:8080` and setup in the backend `port:9090`

Comment: @aldrin27 sorry to post the wrong picture. Actually I tried both (8080/9090) as I thought port 8080 might be occupied. None of them succeed.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem! Why did nobody ever answer that?